# Find $C$ such that $\|f\|^2_2 \leq C \| f' \|^2_2$ for all $ f \in C^1[0,1]$ with $ f(0) = f(1) = 0 $ as minimum as possible.

Tags: calculus, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Find $C$ such that $\|f\|^2_2 \leq C \| f' \|^2_2$ for all $ f \in C^1[0,1]$ with $ f(0) = f(1) = 0 $ as minimum as possible.

Here is the proof for inequality: 
\begin{align}
|f(x)| &\leq \int_0^x |f'(s)| ds  ~~~~~~~~~\mbox{by FTC and triangle inequality}-(1)\\
&\leq \Big(\int_0^x|f'(s)|^2ds\Big)^{1/2} \Big(\int_0^x 1 ^2ds\Big)^{1/2} ~~~~~~~~\mbox{by Cauchy inequality} -(2)\\
&\leq \Big(\int_0^1|f'(s)|^2ds\Big)^{1/2} ~ x^{1/2} ~~~~~~-~~~(3) \\
&=  x^{1/2} ~\| f' \|_2
\end{align}
for all $0\leq x \leq 1.$

Then
$$\|f\|^2_2 = \int_0^1 |f|^2 dx \leq \| f' \|_2^2\int_0^1 x~dx = \frac{1}{2}\| f' \|_2^2$$.

(Maybe the condition $f(0) = f(1)$ is not necessary)

I guess that the minimal $C$ is exactly equal to $2$. Now, I want to find a function such that the equality hold
$$\|f\|^2_2 =   \frac{1}{2}\| f' \|_2^2$$.

The equality holds if the three $"="$ hold in proof:

(1) The equality holds in triangle inequality implies $f\geq 0$ or $f \leq 0$

(2) The equality holds in Cauchy inequality implies $f'$ is a constant

(3) The equality holds in third inequality implies that $f'=0$

It is confusing me now....

Comment: You have not used the condition $f(1) = 0$. But even without it, the constant $\frac{1}{2}$ might not be optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\{f\in C^1[0,1]:\ f(0)=f(1)=0\}$. Clearly $\{\sin(n\pi x)\}$ is dense in $X$. Let 
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(n\pi x),a_n\in R$$
and then
$$ f'(x)=\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nn\cos(n\pi x). $$
So
$$ \|f\|_2^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2,\|f'\|_2^2=\frac{\pi^2}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2a_n^2. $$
Hence
$$ \|f\|_2^2\le\frac{1}{\pi^2}\|f'\|_2^2 $$
and "=" holds iff $a_n=0,n\ge2$ or $f(x)=k\sin(\pi x)$ ($k$ is const).

Comment: Isn't $\sin ' = \cos$ ?

Comment: @MartinR, yes, your are right.